# Ошибка в NancyFx: Cannot apply indexing with [] to an expression of type 'method group'

Tags: c#

Я пытаюсь создать класс (модуль Nancy) и получаю следующую ошибку:

> "Error    CS0021  Cannot apply indexing with [] to an expression of type
>   'method group'  ...."

Мой код:

```
using System; using System.Collections.Generic; using System.Linq;
using System.Web; using Nancy; using System.Text;

namespace SinglePageApp1 {
    public class BloodPresureNancy : NancyModule
    {
        public BloodPresureNancy()
        {

            // Вот тут не работает:
            Get["/"] = _ => "Heloooo";
        }
    } 
}
```

[image]

Я добавил ссылки на Nancy и Nancy.Hosting.asp но всё равно не работает :(

<sub>Свободный перевод вопроса [Cannot apply indexing with [] to an expression of type 'method group'   SinglePageApp1. Get["/"] Nancy](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39574057/5752652) от участника  [@Bartek Popielarczyk](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6848922/bartek-popielarczyk).</sub>

Comment: ассоциация: https://stackoverflow.com/q/39574057/

Answer (score 0):

Какую версию Nancy вы используете? Этот синтаксис должен работать в версиях 1.x.

Для версии 2.х используйте следующий вариант:

```
    Get("/", _ => {
        //do work here
     });
```

<sub>Свободный перевод ответа [Cannot apply indexing with [] to an expression of type 'method group' SinglePageApp1. Get["/"] Nancy](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39598222/5752652)  от участника  [@Komeisa](https://stackoverflow.com/users/402780/komeisa).</sub>